# Unknown Account when attempting to .send() with web3

Tags: solidity, web3js, walletconnect

```
  mintNFT(ether, percentage) {
this.contract.methods
  .createCollectible(parseInt(percentage))
  .send({from: this.props.props.account, value: parseInt(ether) })
  .then((balance) => {
    console.log(balance);
  });
```

}

Error: unknown account is coming up while trying to run this function. .call() is working fine. I'm using walletConnect in the app. I'm wondering what the mechanism is for signing the transaction and how that needs to be set up, as my hunch is that may be where my problem is. Any other thoughts welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

This fixed it, enabling metamask to help sign the transaction.

```
web3.setProvider(window.ethereum);
```